# Why in the fragment inside the bottomNavigation, the request is not sent to the server from the second time onwards

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation and when switch between its items In two cases, two different things happen :
First : When the program is first run -> Everything works fine  . that's mean:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9lZ.jpg)

Exactly when I debug:
First we enter onSuccess and  livedata valued and finally we listen to it in the fragment And finally we see the list of products in the shopping cart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KWrO.jpg)

So far, so good  But :
Second: When the program is run and After adding other products to the cart and refer to the shopping cart item for the second time  : We do not see any new products added.

After debugging, I realized that when the program is run for the first time, the code snippet inside the init{} block is executed, and as a result, we receive the products of the shopping cart on the server side.
But for the second time after, when we click on the shopping cart item, we only listen to the live data, and in fact, the code snippet inside Init is not executed so that we can receive the server-side products.
Now my question is:
My main problem is with the shopping cart item.
What can I do to change items and return to the cart to receive recently added products?
In fact, when I come to the shopping cart item for the second time, what should I do to execute the code snippet inside Init{} AND To be able to see the new products stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the onCreateView method is executed, it causes the init block to be executed only once. The solution is to destroy the piece